# Please rename [codenameone] to [codename-one]

Tags: support, tags

The tag [codenameone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codenameone) should be renamed to [codename-one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codename-one) better to reflect the site's official name.

[image: Codename One]

A view from [@Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) on [whether on not to hyphenate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2813/should-tags-take-the-form-foobar-or-foo-bar) (in general).

Test for Google hits from `codenameone` :    80,600
Test for Google hits from `codename one`: 8,870,000

(first hit for both is the same.)

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codename_One):

[image: Part of Wikipedia page]

From [GitHub](https://github.com/codenameone):

[image: GitHub example]

From Google:

[image: Google example]

From Linkedin:

[image: Linkedin Shai Almog]

[image: Linkedin Chen Fishbein]

From DuckDuckGo:

[image: DuckDuckGo example]

From edits to Usage guide:

[image]

Comment: Are puns only allowed in burnination requests? Otherwise "The name's one, [codename-one] (not [codenameone])" would be ideal

Comment: _"code[anemone](https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/07/12/21/57/sea-anemones-2498495_960_720.jpg)"_?

Comment: It's codenameone.com and codename-one.com so I'm not sure if that would be an improvement. It's also github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne

Comment: Just so we are clear https://www.codenameone.com/about.html

Comment: I'm assuming you mean twitter? I only used that because CodenameOne was taken

Comment: I'm not saying the name of the company isn't "Codename One" I am saying that as a tag using a single word spelling is consistent with how we sometimes spell it. Otherwise our website name would have been codename-one.com. I don't really see any motivation behind that change?

Comment: That's not what I'm asking and not what I'm debating. I'm saying this: codenameone is a common spelling for tags, package names, projects etc. that we use when referencing the project. The spelling in this way is familiar and I'm by a pretty huge margin the most active poster in said tag... I specifically created it that way because I think it's the right way (despite spelling it Codename One when writing English and not tags). If anyone should care about a "mistake" it should be me. I don't think it's a mistake. Why do you care about it?

Comment: BTW I don't mean this in any offensive way, I honestly don't understand why this matters to you?

Comment: How does that help stack overflow? It's not like it would clarify or help people find the tag better. It would just confuse people who are already used to the tag as it is now.

Comment: TS: "Change code name [codenameone] to [codename-one]"

Comment: @ShaiAlmog "Codename One" becomes `codename-one` as a tag on SO. Whether you abbreviate it differently elsewhere doesn't matter. "Visual Studio" becomes `visual-studio`, even though `visualstudio.com` is the name of a website.

Comment: Is there a rule you can point out? Is there a benefit to that for stackoverflow? I'm trying to understand why this would matter to anyone? Notice that with Codename One it's not just the domain but the way we reference it usually in social and in the source code. I don't think that exists for the case of visual studio

Comment: That covers the space to hyphen and even gives the visual studio example. It doesn't cover the importance of picking a specific name when there is ambiguity or disagreement about that from tag commenters which is what I'm asking. I get that you think it should be "Codename One" as the person who named the company/project & tag I don't agree. I get that this isn't "my site". But where are the community rules that say I'm wrong? Doesn't my expert opinion as the guy who came up with the name matter as the authoritative answer here?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Is the name post to read as "Codename One" or "Codenameone"? If it post to be read as "Codename One"; then, the name is meant to have a space. Any variation is either a mistake or because spaces are an illegal character in that particular situation.

Comment: When we write it in English we separate the 2 words. However, in code and in online names we often glue them together. In only one case did we use an underscore on twitter where some other guy took the codenameone as a single word. I'm saying codenameone would be familiar and codename-one wouldn't be as familiar. I think there is reasonable separation between English spelling and Tagging/code/online and we already have a convention for the latter.  What I don't understand is why is everyone in this thread bothered by this?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I believe the generally idea for StackOverFlow tags is that they represent how the tag is post to be read and spoken; however, spaces were an illegal character. To get around the illegal character a standard of replacing spaces with "-" was used. Since "Codename One" is how it is meant to be read and spoken the tag should be "codename-one"; because, that makes it mimic how StacKOverFlow has been approaching tags.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog On the topic of people being bothered by this... I suppose you can say it's a passion for StackOverFlow? A forum gets messy if a  standardized structure for its features is not maintained. As far as I see it, the only drive StackOverFlow people would have is to maintain the structure, You have used many different variations of the name so that doesn't seem like a big issue to you. For that same reason, I'm not sure why you are making a big deal out of this. StackOverFlow has a standard in place, why not follow it?

Comment: So why isn't it named stack-overflow? For me this would be a pain unlike all of you I actually use this tag a lot. So every reference I ever made to the tag would be wrong (yes I know it would be aliased but it would be a redirect and odd to users). Had you come back in 2012 when I created the tag... This seems like one of those arbitrary things that some people around here decide to nitpick despite the fact that it doesn't contribute anything tangible. Also as a site that hails meritocracy I don't think you can go higher than the guy who named the damn thing ;-)

Comment: And https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow what I'm saying is it's nitpicking. It's fine to nitpick about something you are passionate about. It's fine to have some OCDish need to cleanup something you think is "wrong" but to me this seems excessive and counter productive.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog, but on the related tags you have https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange. So it's possible that the **stackoverflow** one will be fixed in the future.

Comment: What I am saying is: It doesn't provide any benefit. It does cause a hassle if you change it. The rules to do that discuss cases where there is consensus about tag spelling. Here there seems to be a consensus only from people who haven't used it... A big problem is that this discussion is happening in the meta tag. If you had it within the tag itself the overwhelming consensus would be bewilderment over why would you do that and most people would ignore it.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog: little differences like `codenameone` and `codename-one` are the reason we have tag synonyms.

Answer (score 2):

Normally I'd agree with the request, however, one of the founders posted [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364041/please-rename-codenameone-to-codename-one/377668#comment561981_364041) in the comments under your question (emphasis mine):

> I'm saying this: **codenameone is a common spelling for tags, package names, projects etc. that we use when referencing the project. The spelling in this way is familiar** and I'm by a pretty huge margin the most active poster in said tag... I specifically created it that way because I think it's the right way (despite spelling it Codename One when writing English and not tags). If anyone should care about a "mistake" it should be me. I don't think it's a mistake.

I believe in practice over theory, so I think we should keep the current tag name.